# has_parent not working with filtered in elasticsearch 1.3.0

Tags: elasticsearch

In **elasticsearch 1.3.0** has_parent and filtered not working under query. Whereas separately it's working in **elasticsearch 1.3.0**. This query is working in old  **elasticsearch 0.90.5** version.

I am using below query.

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
      "has_parent": {
         "type": "url",
         "query": {
            "filtered": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must_not": {
                        "terms": {
                           "affiliate_id": [
                              "1625024208"
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     "must": {
                        "terms": {
                           "affiliate_id": [
                              "1718654495"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": {
                  "terms": {
                     "country": [
                        "India"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Getting error message `ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "filtered"`

**Complete Error Message:**

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
  shardFailures {[hZgYLUmsQL2T8z1MY2eyNA][esindex][5]: SearchParseException[[esindex][5]:
    query[parent_filter[url](filtered(affiliate_id:1718489511)->cache(_type:url))],from[-1],size[-1]:
    Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
      {
        "query": {
          "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "url",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "affiliate_id": "1718489511"
              }
            }
          },
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "terms": {
                    "country": [
                      "india"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]]];
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "filtered"]; }{[OPG4zuQlQr2dFxUvRe2GWg][esindex][4]: 
  RemoteTransportException[[server1][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][search/phase/query]]; 
  nested: SearchParseException[[esindex][4]: 
    query[parent_filter[url](filtered(affiliate_id:1718489511)->cache(_type:url))],from[-1],size[-1]: 
    Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
      {
        "query": {
          "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "url",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "affiliate_id": "1718489511"
              }
            }
          },
          "filtered": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": {
                  "terms": {
                    "country": [
                      "india"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]]];
  nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "filtered"];
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it on Elasticsearch 1.3.0, I suggest a different query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "url",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "terms": {
                  "country": [
                    "india"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "affiliate_id": "1718489511"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query is matching your explanations, what you want to do:

> In this query I need add filtered inside has_parent like has_parent->query->filtered->bool->must

Maybe you should upgrade to a newer Bugfix-Release, as you upgrading from a [ES 0.90.x version](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-3-1-released/)

Comment: Thanks!. I have updated my question with exact query format. Please suggest Query DSL for the same. I am trying your answer including `query->filtered->bool->must`.